# Adding multiple options in database from 3 dropdowns on same form

Tags: php, mysql

I have on one form 3 `<select></select>` fields and each dropdown user can check multiple options. I want to save them in database but can't figure out how to make this.
Here are dropdowns

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="upload_program">Program:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=1";                         
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_program" id="ddlCars2" multiple="multiple">';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_program){

                            echo '<option value='.$row_program['field_name'].'>'.$row_program['field_name'].'</option>'; 
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>                      
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="upload_subject">Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=2";                         
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_subject" id="ddlCars1" multiple="multiple">';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_subject){
                            echo '<option value='.$row_subject['field_name'].'>'.$row_subject['field_name'].'</option>';                                
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="upload_grade_level">Grade Level:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=4";                         
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_grade_level" id="ddlCars3" multiple="multiple">';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_grade_level){
                            echo '<option value='.$row_grade_level['field_name'].'>'.$row_grade_level['field_name'].'</option>';                                
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>                      
            </div>
```

this is how I show them on the page. Here is the query to insert them but doesn't insert all the options checked..

```
$upload_program = $_POST['upload_program'];
$upload_subject = $_POST['upload_subject'];
$upload_grade_level = $_POST['upload_grade_level'];

$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (upload_program, upload_subject, upload_grade_level) VALUES (:upload_program, :upload_subject, :upload_grade_level)');

        $stmt1->execute(array(
                ':upload_program' => $upload_program,
                ':upload_subject' => $upload_subject,
                ':upload_grade_level' => $upload_grade_level            
        ));
```

I know that somehow I can take them as array but don't know how..

Comment: use array in echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_program[]" id="ddlCars2" multiple="multiple">';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` array in select dropdown for multiple select option.

Syntax:

```
<select name="test[]" id="dropdown1" multiple="multiple">
```

In PHP you can get values in post array with select name like in above example you will get value in `$_POST['test']` array.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="upload_program">Program:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=1";                         
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_program[]" id="ddlCars2" multiple="multiple">';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_program){

                            echo '<option value='.$row_program['field_name'].'>'.$row_program['field_name'].'</option>'; 
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>                      
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="upload_subject">Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=2";                         
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_subject[]" id="ddlCars1" multiple="multiple">';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_subject){
                            echo '<option value='.$row_subject['field_name'].'>'.$row_subject['field_name'].'</option>';                                
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="upload_grade_level">Grade Level:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql="SELECT field_name FROM form_fields WHERE group_id=4";                         
                        echo '<select class="form-control" name="upload_grade_level[]" id="ddlCars3" multiple="multiple">';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row_grade_level){
                            echo '<option value='.$row_grade_level['field_name'].'>'.$row_grade_level['field_name'].'</option>';                                
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>                      
            </div>
```

**PHP**

Using implode() you can change your selected option from array to string for storing it in database table.

```
$upload_program = implode(",",$_POST['upload_program']); // You will get value with comma seperated
$upload_subject = implode(",",$_POST['upload_subject']);
$upload_grade_level = implode(",",$_POST['upload_grade_level']);

$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (upload_program, upload_subject, upload_grade_level) VALUES (:upload_program, :upload_subject, :upload_grade_level)');

        $stmt1->execute(array(
                ':upload_program' => $upload_program,
                ':upload_subject' => $upload_subject,
                ':upload_grade_level' => $upload_grade_level            
        ));
```

Comment: I was away from the pc for a while. Just tried it and it's working like a charm. Just one last thing. Now when I retrieve them in another page since they are stored in field in comma how to retrieved and show them? Like normal query and echo?

Comment: Use FIND_IN_SET("search_value", "database_comma_seperated_values"). Also accept the correct answer @Jordan Vi

Comment: Can you show me simple example with this `FIND_IN_SET("search_value", "database_comma_seperated_values")` I have never use it before and I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: Sample Query is : $sql="SELECT field_name FROM tablename WHERE FIND_IN_SET(".$searchValue.",upload_program)"; In this $searchValue contain your search string which you use at the time of retrieve.

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure it out how to use this function in my query to show all of the values in comma separated table. What this mean `In this $searchValue contain your search string which you use at the time of retrieve`?

Comment: are you still not able to conclude or confuse? tell me what type of help you need and where you facing issue. @Jordan Vit

Comment: I was able to make it. I read some tutorial and find the answer there. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

For multiple option to get select your select name should be array and apart you will get that in post with array of select_name which you can implode it